# Has zram been removed in the latest ubuntu (17.10)?

Tags: swap, zram

When running `sudo modprobe zram` (or `modinfo` for that matter) I get the following error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module zram not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-21-generic
```

Has zram been removed from Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: It works on my 17.10 system: `filename: /lib/modules/4.13.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/block/zram/zram.ko`.

Comment: Is that on a live 17.10 / ISO? Maybe you installed/removed something that took out zram with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Kernel modules are pretty rarely removed from the upstream kernel. However, many modules are split into a separate (versioned) `linux-image-extra` package in Ubuntu, and you may be missing said package for your kernel version.

Comment: And as expected, that's what the package index shows: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=zram.ko

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual` which installed the version specific `linux-image-extra` stuff too. :)

Comment: I'm on rpi ubuntu server 22 '5.15.0-1006-raspi' and used that official imager thingy. If I "install" an older version kernel/package that has zram module, does that replace/rollback the entire system (kernel?) and break everything else just to have zram?

Comment: Solved it with `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-1006-raspi` thanks to your help. I just realized this was in 2017 but found the newer stuff using that package search.